# Is it possible to make an alarm ring at a given hour regardless of the timezone

Tags: android, timezone, alarmmanager

I need to make an alarm ring at a given hour, regardless of the timezone the device is on.

My usecase is the following : I have to make an alarm ring at a given hour on user's clock (changing every day, so I need to schedule it everyday and cannot use [`AlarmManager#setRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))) , with a possible timezone change in the meantime (between alarm set and alarm ring hour).

The problem is that [`AlarmManage#set`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) using [`RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) is setting the alarm to ring depending on UTC time using [`System#currentTimeMillis`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()). Thus when changing timezone, as the alarm is ringing at given UTC time, it rings at a different user's wall clock.

How can I deal with this ?